# Simple contract on private network is never mined

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, contract-debugging, private-blockchain

I'm trying to run the [crowdsale example](https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale) from the Frontier docs on a private network and local blockchain.  I can create the contract, but do not seem to be able to mine it.

You can see a gist of the code I'm running in the `geth` console [here](https://gist.github.com/jtobin/832b2df8278c2e07055f).

In particular, the crowdsale example involves two contracts: one called `token` and one called `Crowdsale`.  I can compile these fine with `solc`; given the contracts' source in `crowdSrc` and an unlocked account named 'foo', the following code creates the `token` contract as expected:

```
var crowdCompiled = eth.compile.solidity(crowdSrc);

var tokenContract = eth.contract(crowdCompiled.token.info.abiDefinition);

var token = tokenContract.new(
    10000
  , { from: foo
    , data: crowdCompiled.token.code
    , gas:  300000
    }
  , function(e, contract) {
      if(!e) {
        if(!contract.address) {
        console.log(
          "Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " +
          contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
      } else {
        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
      }
    }
  })
```

This is mined almost instantaneously when I start mining with a couple of threads via `miner.start(2)`:

```
Contract mined! Address: 0xaacc2f82f12a54172a0eb6b499a91578a5b7e0b5
```

and I can check its address:

```
> token.address
"0xaacc2f82f12a54172a0eb6b499a91578a5b7e0b5"
```

Now.  `crowdCompiled` also contains the compiled code for the `Crowdsale` contract, so I can create it from the unlocked account 'foo' like so:

```
var crowdContract = eth.contract(crowdCompiled.Crowdsale.info.abiDefinition);

var _beneficiary = foo;
var _fundingGoal = parseInt(web3.toWei(100, 'ether'));
var _duration    = 5;
var _price       = parseInt(web3.toWei(0.02, 'ether'));
var _reward      = token.address;

var crowdsale = crowdContract.new(
    _beneficiary
  , _fundingGoal
  , _duration
  , _price
  , _reward
  , { from: foo
    , data: crowdCompiled.Crowdsale.code
    , gas:  300000
    }
  , function(e, contract) {
      if (!e) {
        if (!contract.address) {
          console.log(
            "contract transaction send: hash " + contract.transactionHash +
            " waiting to be mined.");
          } else {
            console.log("contract mined, address " + contract.address);
            }
        }});
```

Again it is created fine:

```
contract transaction send: hash 0xc813953780a364f91f339a711a301188f9c546a29915ae19fd1722e335076ad8 waiting to be mined.
```

But it seemingly takes far longer than expected to finish mining this contract, if it indeed finishes at all.  I've kicked off `miner.start(2)` and waited for over fifty blocks to go through numerous times, but I've never actually managed to mine the contract.

When the miner is active I can confirm that `crowdsale._eth.hashrate` is a valid number (e.g. 139791, 206544, etc.).  Checking `crowdsale.address` yields `undefined`.

Why is this simple contract taking so long to mine?  Have I missed something, or is this behaviour possibly due to a bug?  Are there any useful web3 methods or other tips I'm missing to help diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possibility is that you are running out of gas (i.e. deploying the contract requires more computation than you allowed). Please raise the gas limit to 3 million and try again to see if tis is the issue.

More generally, if you see issues like this you might want to increase logging to see if some error occurs and what that is exactly. One useful way would be `--vmdebug` which creates huge stack dumps of exactly what the EVM is doing, which if terminates with `OUT OF GAS`, then you immediately have your answer :)

Comment: Brilliant - this instantly fixed the problem.  I had misunderstood what 'gas' was actually specifying in contract deployment and was actually trying to set it as *low* as possible!  Cheers.

Comment: Any unused gas is returned to the person executing the transaction, so go ahead an fill up the tank. If on the other hand the transaction goes OUT OG GAS, all gas is lost.